# Highschool question regarding kinetic energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy

I am stuck in a basic problem for some reason. The problem is the following:

> We have a body moving. In position A it has kinetic energy equal to K1 = 80J. I need to find the kinetic energy K2 at position B, when the only horizotal power is the resistance T=5N. We also know that g=10 and that the Δx that it moved is 4m

So from my understanding, we have a decreasing movement, thus we use the appropriate equations (basically with a minus) and we have a starting speed that we do not know. However, I am unable to reach a number

Edit:
So I know that the equations I should use are :

- The body is having a decreasing movement since the only power at point B is the traction (resistance T=5N)
- ΣF = ma (since the body is having a decreasing movement)
- u = u_0 -a*t
- x = u_0*t - 1/2 *a*t^2
- K = 1/2 * m * u^2

From ΣF = ma we can substitute to be T=m*a thus 5=m*a
We also know that K = 1/2 * m * u^2 thus 80 =  1/2 * m * u^2
and from x = u_0*t - 1/2 *a*t^2 we get 4 =1/2 * m * u^2

However I am unable to understand how to solve that system to find K2

Edit2 : I read about the Work Energy theorem. So perhaps the solution is the following? :

- W_b = F*x = T*x = 5*4 = 20
- K_b - K_a = W_b thus W_b = 100?

Comment: Hello Alex and welcome to Physics SE. I suggest you post what your approach to tackle the issue is, what you have tried so far and where you got stuck. This will allow other users to back you up and help. Generally, the more information you provide, the easier will be for other people to help.

Comment: Higher kinetic energy means moving faster. As a check, is it supposed to speed up or slow down?

Comment: Hey Sean. Yeah that s a good point. From my understanding the body should slow down since the only power we have is the resistance which is opposing to our movement. Oh perhaps my W is -2o because T is opposing to our direction? Thus K_final -80 = -20/ Thus K_final = 60?

Answer (score 0):

To be sure, I'd need to see the diagram, but I think $g$ is a red herring. If there's no movement in the $y$-direction then $g$ cannot do any work, and can, therefore, not change the kinetic energy. The rest is just the work-energy theorem, for which you should have a formula that you'll have to memorize.

Comment: hello thank you for answering. I have updated the question. I am unable to basically solve the system